# Spring not finding Hibernate mappings file

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, file-not-found, enunciate

So I am taking Enunciate for a spin and have run into an issue when my servlet starts up. For some reason, despite the file being there, in the classpath, and everything being specified correctly, Spring tells me the following:

```
09-15@15:36:31 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-user-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/classes/resources/hibernate.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:471)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4216)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/classes/resources/hibernate.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:142)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:656)
```

The structure is that I have applicationContext.xml (generated by Enunciate), web.xml and spring-user-config.xml inside WEB-INF and then hibernate.xml at WEB-INF/classes/resources.

I've tried it all, relative vs. absolute paths, using "classpath:", and I just can't think of any other reason why it wouldn't be found.

This is where the sessionFactory bean is declared inside my spring-user-config.xml file:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <ref bean="exampleHibernateProperties"/>
        </property>
        <!-- Must references all OR mapping files. -->
        <property name="mappingResources" value="WEB-INF/classes/resources/hibernate.xml">
      </property>
</bean>
```

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated guys!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just

```
<property name="mappingResources" value="resources/hibernate.xml" />
```

Comment: Man, what was I thinking. That was it. Thanks a bunch. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, my Eclipse configuration didn't add WEB-INF/classes directory and I wasn't aware that it was searching for this file here. If there are any others out there struggling with this problem (it cost me a few hours of fiddling/googling!), then create the WEB-INF/classes directory and copy any hibernate resource files into it (or a sub-directory, as specified in mappingResources).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I've been go through the same pain. I have to manually create the WEB-INF/classes folder in order to get it work only in development.

Answer (score 1):

If ur using any IDE better place the hibernate.xml in Source folder.In runtime it automatically adds to the classpath and in configuration you can just add classpath:

```
<property name="mappingResources">
<value> classpath:hibernate.xml </value>
  </property>
```